Forge Viewer, shader material does not work with existing objects in the model
I can't use the shader for objects that are already in the model. I referred to this link (link)(link). But it doesn't change color, even with useWebGL2: false or true.
After that, I downloaded this code, ran it locally, but couldn't change the heatmap color. The error is as shown below.err image
When I add a new THREE.Mesh object to the overlay scene, the shader can be used.
If I use frags.setMaterial for THREE.MeshBasicMaterial, then the objects in the model can change color.
The code I used is as follows.
function applyCustomMaterialToSelection(viewer) {
  const VertexShader = `
    void main() {
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
  `;
  const FragmentShader = `
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
  `;
 
  // Create and register a new shader material
  const customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: VertexShader,
    fragmentShader: FragmentShader
  });
  customMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
  const materialManager = viewer.impl.matman();
    var customMaterialsss  = customMaterial 
  materialManager.addMaterial('myCustomMaterial', customMaterialsss, true /* skip material heuristics */);
 
  // Assign the new material to selected objects
  const model = viewer.model;
  model.unconsolidate(); // If the model is consolidated, material changes won't have any effect
  const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
  const frags = model.getFragmentList();
  const dbids = viewer.getSelection();
  for (const dbid of dbids) {
    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, (fragid) => {
      frags.setMaterial(fragid, customMaterialsss);
    });
  }
}
applyCustomMaterialToSelection(viewer)


Thank you for the heads up. It looks like something has changed in the viewer rendering pipeline that's breaking the way the custom materials are used here. I've contacted the viewer team and will report here as soon as I get their answer.
